# SQL Full differences between Tables

Tags: c#, sql, inner-join, outer-join

in my C# project I describe some devices with a SQL Table where all the functions are described with several paramenters, for example:

```
Function    Position   Default ...
Autoreset   5          0
Power       9          1
Adjust      0          22
...
```

sometimes it happens that a new version replace the previous one and usually a new version has little changes respect to the previous one. Just to give you an example, it is possible to have

- function removed
- function added
- function changed in some parameters (in the previous example, the new version can have the Power default changed from 1 to 6)
- ...

What I'd like to see are the changes in a table but not simply the list of differences between the two table, but for example a table with:

1. common values as normal text
2. values added in red bold
3. values removed in gray
4. values changed in green

My idea was to use the JOIN command in order to have three tables:

1. Table with common values
2. Table with differences from Table1 and Table2 (value added in table2)
3. Table with differences from Table2 and Table1 (value added in table1)

I started the development from SQL with the folowing instruction

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("select * from " + TableName1 + "  FULL OUTER JOIN " + TableName2 + " ON " + TableName1 + ".FieldName="+ TableName2 +".FieldName", conn);
```

but it seems that I need to specify all columns. Is it possible do a JOIN for all columns?

BR

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get how you store your data between different tables but basically you need to see differences between tables based on Function column ONLY. If you enlist ALL your columns, in the result set you'll get not-NULL rows only for the records that match by ALL columns. So to determine differences your select should be:

`select *
from TCommon
full join T1 on TCommon.[Function] = T1.[Function]
full join T2 on TCommon.[Function] = T2.[Function]`

The result will give you values from table if found by [Function] or NULL if not. As for coloring the differences between attributes, I would determine differences in C#.

In the most common option your result set will be

```
TCommon.[Function]    TCommon.A1    T1.[Function]    T1.A1    T2.[Function]    T2.[A1]
Autoreset             1             Autoreset        2        NULL             NULL
Power                 2             NULL             NULL     Power            3
Adjust                3             NULL             NULL     Adjust           3
...
```

NULL values means the item doesn't exist (was removed or not added), difference in attributes means the attribute was changed.